# Maven build is not getting feature installed properly

Tags: maven, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

When trying to configure my pom.xml file with the passwordUtilities feature, messages.log always seems to show that the feature is not installed during server startup, even though it's in the feature manager list and I can see all the required feature files in wlp/lib.  This is what I currently have coded in pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <assemblyArtifact>
        <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>wlp-javaee7</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.0.4</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </assemblyArtifact>                 
    <configFile>src/main/liberty/config/server.xml</configFile>
    <include>${packaging.type}</include>
    <bootstrapProperties>
        <appContext>${warContext}</appContext>
        <default.http.port>${testServerHttpPort}</default.http.port>
        <default.https.port>${testServerHttpsPort}</default.https.port>
        <appLocation>${project.artifactId}.war</appLocation>
    </bootstrapProperties>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>install-feature</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>install-feature</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <features>
                <acceptLicense>true</acceptLicense>
                <feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>                    
            </features>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `install-feature` goal needs to be bound to the `prepare-package` phase, (according to [the doc](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven#packaging-types)) as opposed to the `pre-integration-test` phase.

Also, I should point out that if you omit features from your `<features>` configuration, then the server.xml will be scanned and missing features will be automatically downloaded.

So your new `<exection>` stanza would look like this:

```
<execution>
    <id>install-feature</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-feature</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <features>
            <acceptLicense>true</acceptLicense>
        </features>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Cool, I got past the passwordUtilities not installed message in messages.log.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, That's correct.  We have fixed a misleading example in the `install-feature` documentation: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/install-feature.md#install-feature.